Why am I getting this Error when I am deploying movie-recommender-system on streamlit,KeyError: poster_path?
KeyError: 'poster_path'
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\.venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 542, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 63, in <module>
    names,posters = recommend(selected_movie_name)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 45, in recommend
    recommended_movies_poster.append(fetch_poster(movie_id))
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 32, in fetch_poster
    return "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + data['poster_path']
                                           ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I want to show posters of movies.

your getting the error because data dictionary does not have that key.   You should provide the code that is  generating the exception.   right now its impossible to recommend a fix because we have zero context to work with.
